# Encryption key in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

The CodeIgniter 2.0.2 requires to set an encryption key in the config file i.e. `$config['encryption_key']` , if you want to use Session class. Can it be *any* string? Any example of secure encryption_key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> The key should be as random as possible and it must not be a regular
>   text string, nor the output of a hashing function, etc.

To save your key to your **application/config/config.php**, open the file and set:

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'yourKeyHere'
```

[Random Key Generator](https://randomkeygen.com/)

> It's important for you to know that the encoded messages the encryption function generates will be approximately 2.6 times longer than the original message. For example, if you encrypt the string "my super secret data", which is 21 characters in length, you'll end up with an encoded string that is roughly 55 characters (we say "roughly" because the encoded string length increments in 64 bit clusters, so it's not exactly linear). Keep this information in mind when selecting your data storage mechanism. Cookies, for example, can only hold 4K of information.

Comment: +1 for information about the cookie size, I didn't think about it until I read this and used some random complex key

Answer (score 18):

In addition to the answer by Chumillas, I personally use this [Random Key Generator](http://randomkeygen.com/) for my CodeIgniter encryption strings. Quick and easy.

Comment: from what Chumillas has said, would using the 256bit encryption key supplied by that website be multiplied 2.6 times? If it is, wouldn't that take up a lot more space in the cookies?

Comment: I suppose it would. However, CodeIgniter recommends a random 32 character encryption key (like that provided from the Random Key Generator) to take maximum advantage of the encryption algorithm according to: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html

Answer (score 8):

Codeigniter 3.1.0
**YOU MUST NOT USE REGULAR TEXT FOR 'encryption_key'**

"The key should be as random as possible and it must **not be a regular text string**, nor the output of a hashing function, etc. In order to create a proper key, you must use the Encryption library’s create_key() method"

```
$this->load->library('encryption');
$key = $this->encryption->create_key(16);
// Get a hex-encoded representation of the key:
$key = bin2hex($this->encryption->create_key(16));

// Put the same value in your config with hex2bin(),
// so that it is still passed as binary to the library:
$config['encryption_key'] = hex2bin(<your hex-encoded key>);
```

**Source: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/encryption.html#setting-your-encryption-key**

Comment: I know the config setting going in config.php, but where do you put the setting of the $key?

Comment: Just as reference, the answer from the CI Forum: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-68741.html

Comment: How to pass that generated **$key** to config file $config['encryption_key'] ?

Answer (score 2):

Type this into your terminal:

```
php -r 'echo bin2hex(random_bytes(16)), "\n";'
```

It'll output a string where you update your config.php

Answer (score 1):

Just go to application/config

open config.php file

find out the word

```
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
```

replace this with

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'your_encryption_key_here';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code in my app's installer. It takes 128 bytes of random data (converted to a hex string), and takes two characters at a time, converting to decimal, and checking they're in an acceptable range (alphanumeric, with symbols, no whitespace or characters that won't play nice with your editor or config file - aka no ')

32 characters is 128 bits, so it works well with the block cipher.

```
function random_key_string() {
    $source = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(128));
    $string = '';
    $c = 0;
    while(strlen($string) < 32) { 
        $dec = gmp_strval(gmp_init(substr($source, $c*2, 2), 16),10);
        if($dec > 33 && $dec < 127 && $dec !== 39)
            $string.=chr($dec);
        $c++;
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Karimkorun - I'm looking to set this key through an installer myself and came across your answer. How do you go about writing the value to the config file? Does code igniter provide a convenient method for this?

Comment: I wrote an installer to do this, as it's an open source app.. You could write a CLI script to generate the config file when you create a new application.

Answer (score -2):

To save your key to your **application/config/config.php**, open the file and set:

on line 227 `$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";`

Comment: $myconfig =&get_config(); $key = $myconfig['encryption_key']; // and to get it